# How to tell if android device has been turned off

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an re-occurring alarm manager task that needs to run nightly, However when the device is turned off then back on, it erases this task and I have no way to reset it.  I would like to know how to tell if a device has been turned off and/or if you can run specific code before the phone turns off so I can set a flag to reset this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Register for the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission and set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts.